# email from bash script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
MESSAGE="Line one. /n"

MESSAGE="$MESSAGE Line two. /n"
MESSAGE="$MESSAGE Line three."

echo $MESSAGE | mail -s "test" "example@example.com"
```

Is that how I should get each line, on its own line?

Comment: Jim, welcome to StackOverflow. Please remember to format your code samples by selecting them and hitting the "code" button (the one with ones and zeros on it).

Comment: Thanks for the code button tip :)

Answer (score 16):

Use a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

```
mail -s "test" "example@example.com" << END_MAIL
Line one.
Line two.
Line three.
END_MAIL
```

Comment: If you quote the first delimiter (here `END_MAIL`) it will prevent parameter expansion, command substitution, etc., which may be desirable.

Answer (score 9):

Change:

```
echo $MESSAGE | mail -s "test" "example@example.com"
```

To:

```
echo -e $MESSAGE | mail -s "test" "example@example.com"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The `-e` switch expands the `\n` newline characters as expected and is easier to use in a script on a single line than the heredoc method.

Answer (score 2):

The heredoc advice is good, plus you might want to consider using `mailx` for which there exists a Posix standard or perhaps `sendmail` which will exist if the mailer is either sendmail or postfix. (I'm not sure about qmail.)

Unless using sendmail, it's also a good idea to set the `MAILRC` variable to `/dev/null` to bypass the user's configuration script, if any.

Comment: I'm a big fan of using `sendmail` in shell scripts. +1