# Testing multiple unix server Connectivity using ping command and send mail the hostname/ipaddress of the servers if any hosts are unreachable

Tags: shell, unix

Testing multiple unix server Connectivity using ping command and send mail the hostname/ip-address of the servers if any hosts are unreachable

There is file `host.txt` which contain the list of the servers we want to ping 
for e.g

```
www.abc.domain01.com
www.abc.domain02.com
www.abc.domain03.com
www.abc.domain04.com
```

in this case i'm considering there are total four servers ; but it can be 100 servers 
i know how to check the connectivity of multiple servers but i don't know how to get the mail if particular server(s) is unreachable 
MY CODE IS

```
email=XXXXXXXXXXXXX@domain.com
for i in $(cat host.txt)
do 
      ping -c4 $i 

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then 

echo "$i is unreachable"|mail -s "ping alert" $email 
    fi
done
```

suppose server `www.abc.domain01.com` is unreachable so i want see the output in my mail like `www.abc.domain01.com`

Comment: possible duplicate of [email from bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275593/email-from-bash-script)

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here. What is your evidence that it is not working? Does `echo "test from my server" | mail -s "mailTest" myAddr@myMailHost.com` work? If not, then `sendmail` probably isn't work, or there are rules that are blocking your message or numerous other things. Real error messages are best in your question. Good luck.

Comment: It was the problem with  mail , now it is working well . i have one doubts ... i don't want to display the output  of the ping on screen .Once i run this script i just want  alert in my email . where i should redirect the output , Please help me with this .

Comment: as you're testing ping status with `$?`, you can redirect `ping` output to /dev/null, i.e. `ping -c4 $i 2>/dev/null`. Check `man ping`. maybe your version has something like `-s` for silent.