# Write the bash shell script to test the ping against multiple server and send the report to email for unresponsive servers

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

```
#! /bin/bash
email=xxxxxxxxx@domain.com
for i in $(cat ping.txt)
do
fping $i >/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo "$i is down"|mailx -s "connectivity test" $email
fi
done
```

This script is working fine but the problem is it is sending the mail individually for each host ,suppose number of unreachable server is more ( in three digit ) .. i don't think this is best practice to do this

i want see list of down hosts in one email ,could you help me to modify the script .. i am new in shell scripting please help . Many Thanks

Reference :-

[Testing multiple unix server Connectivity using ping command and send mail the hostname/ipaddress of the servers if any hosts are unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335763/testing-multiple-unix-server-connectivity-using-ping-command-and-send-mail-the-h)

Comment: store the text in some variable and send the mail at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A monitoring system that's specifically designed for this sort of task would be the best tool.  Examples include Nagios, Icinga or Zabbix.

However, if you really want to do it with bash, here's one way.  It will only send an email if at least one host does not respond to a ping.

```
#!/bin/bash

email=xxxxxxxxx@domain.com
NBR_DOWN=0
LOGFILE=/tmp/pinglog.txt

echo "Connectivity Test Results" > $LOGFILE
for i in $(cat ping.txt); do
    fping $i >/dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "$i is down" >> $LOGFILE
        NBR_DOWN=$((NBR_DOWN+1))
    fi
done

if [ $NBR_DOWN -gt 0 ]; then
    mailx -s "connectivity test" $email < $LOGFILE
fi
```

Comment: Cool. Mind accepting my answer then? I could use the reputation points. ;)

Comment: sure,Thanks  Brian

Comment: i have one question : increments the counter by 1 at each pass NBR_DOWN=$((NBR_DOWN+1))  or we can use " let NBR_DOWN++ "

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash for more examples. Sure, you could use that LET statement. You could also use ((NBR_DOWN++)).